# For a given image $\mathbf X$, the equivalence class for pixels $p$ with labels $l$.

Tags: equivalence-relations, image-processing

> $\left[l\right]=\left\{p \in\mathbf X|\,p\sim l\right\}$.

This is taken from [this paper](https://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://archive.nlm.nih.gov/pubs/pubPDFs/HISB-ghosh.pdf&ei=tVm5UdusKYbk8gSIvYDAAw&usg=AFQjCNFYnYEKcd7DVZRSPc1XqlC14dISSQ&sig2=4ZDNgIpNLt9VPa_8k4ANGQ&bvm=bv.47883778,d.eWU) on image segmentation, page $2$. I don't know how to interpret this, do they mean "all the pixels on image $\mathbf X$ that share a label $l$ on algorithm step $t$ become equivalent"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The equivalence classes partition **X** by grouping together the pixels with the same label. For the purposes of this algorithm, pixels that share the same label are considered equivalent.